# Recording a list in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, csv, import, tuples

I have a csv file with the content:

```
COD_DIST;ID
11;\['42341', '42340', '42342'\]
```

To import this csv to Postgres i use the following code:

```py
         conn = psycopg2.connect(host='x.x.x.x', 
                         database='BASENAME_ANY',
                         user=user, 
                         password=password)    
                         
          curs = conn.cursor()
          with open(filename, "r", encoding='utf-8') as fp:
              #Skip the header row.
              next(fp)
              tup = [tuple(line.strip().split(";")) for line in fp] 
              print(tup)
              args_str = ",".join(curs.mogrify("(%s,%s)", x).decode('utf-8') for x in tup)
              sqlDec = "INSERT INTO " + name_table + " VALUES "
              curs.execute(sqlDec + args_str)
              conn.commit()
              
          curs.close()
          conn.close()
```

I received this message:  `DETAIL: "\[" must introduce explicitly-specified array dimensions...`.
Please, can you help me?

Comment: Read the docs. 1) Correct way to pass [parameters](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries) 2) [List/Array adaption](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#adapt-list).

Comment: I was assuming that you where trying to insert data into a Postgres array. A closer look indicates you may not. To your question add information about what you are trying to achieve?